# How to put something extra while navigate another page in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I created a listpage and when i click in general button in main page i have to navigate the page to listpage and put something extra while navigating it in order to understand which page its going to get the list, otherwise i have to create lots of listpages for every category

```
    private void btn_general_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ListPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the page URI to put contextual data:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ListPage.xaml?list=list1", UriKind.Relative));
```

In `ListPage`, you can then retrieve that data by looking into the `NavigationContext.QueryString` property:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("list"))
    {
        string list = NavigationContext.QueryString["list"];
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("category") , my navigation is this NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ListPage.xaml?category=4", UriKind.Relative));  There is null referance exception in if statement

Comment: @KBB Where have you put your code? You should put it in the `OnNavigatedTo` event

Comment: can you rewrite your answer inside the onNavigateTo method to make other people to understand the concept